# Find Immediate child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
          1 <span data-link="procedurestep"> 

              2. <span data-link="procedurestep"> data1 </span>

            </span>
        
      3. <span data-link="procedurestep"> data2 </span>

          4. <span data-link="procedurestep"> data3 </span>
```

I have access span tag with data-link attribute having the value "main procedure"
Now I want to get those span elements having data-link attribute value as "procedure step"
But only immediate span elements I put numbers for understanding I want 1,3,4 number span, not 2

I tried below code

var children = $(root).find("span[data-link='" + nodeName + "']").eq(nodeNumber);

nodeName is data-link attribute value e.g "procedurestep"

but it gives me all span elements not immediate
Note:- in between spans there me other tags also present like div, table, tr, and td like that

var children = $(root).find("span[data-link='" + nodeName + "']").eq(nodeNumber);

I tried this code but it gets all span elements

Comment: There's a `.children()` method in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [jquery .children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) function to filter the children by your selector:

```
var children = $(root).children("span[data-link='" + nodeName + "']").eq(nodeNumber);
```

Or use the [child combinator `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) so your selector only matches direct descendants of your source element:

```
var children = $(root).find("> span[data-link='" + nodeName + "']").eq(nodeNumber);
```

---

For interest, you can also do this using the native DOM API (i.e. without jQuery) by using the [`:scope` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope):

```
const children = document.querySelector(root).querySelectorAll(":scope > span[data-link='" + nodeName + "']").item(nodeNumber);

// Which is also equivalent to this (depending on needs):
const children = document.querySelectorAll(`${root} > span[data-link="${nodeName}"]`).item(nodeNumber);
```

Comment: But that span elements may be present within div tag 
We have to avoid that div's or any other tags between them

Comment: <span data-link="mainProcedure">
  <div>
   <div>
                 1 <span data-link="procedurestep"> 

                     2. <span data-link="procedurestep"> data1 </span>

                     </span>
         </div>
  </div>
   
       3. <span data-link="procedurestep"> data2 </span>

              4. <span data-link="procedurestep"> data3 </span>

       </span>
like above span elements may be present we have to consider only span tags not div tags